# ¿Como enviar un parámetro por una route con post Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Quisiera enviar un parametro por una ruta desde un controlador, hacia otro , pero resulta que lo tengo como post y no get , quisiera saber como enviar ese parametro al otro controlador , a continuación el code , y un "ejemplo" (Se que debería hacerse con get pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma con post) :

Code:

```php
    return redirect()->route("daem.search,[parametro => valor]")
    ->with(["message" => "No existen registros con la fecha indicada"]);
    //La route daem.search esta como post, no get
```

Answer (score 0):

si lo que desea es realiza un comunicado de un controlador a otro controlador lo puede realiza de la siguiente forma  y es la forma mas recomendada y la mas fácil de hace

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class TestController extends Controller
{

   public function Auditoria(Request $request){

    $Controller =  new  homeController();
    $va = $Controller->HomePrueba(7);
    var_dump($va);

    }

}

?>
```

Archivo de segundo controlador

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class homeController extends Controller
{
public function HomePrueba($id){
    {
        $id =  $id;
        return $id + 1;
    }
}
?>
```

la segunda es con el método post y siempre es el mas complicado, en la cual lo uso para obtener datos del login de otro servidor y hay que tener en cuenta que tiene que añadir el toke o le genera un error 401 , pero en lo genera es mejor usar el primer método por la simplicidad y la facilidad de obtener los datos.

```
  public function CamaraAdaLoginPost()
        {
            //Url:: Home/CamaraAdaLoginPost
            $postdata = json_encode(array(
'parametro' => 'Daca', 
'username' => 'Data de usuario', 
'Password' => 'contraseña'
));
            $opts = array(
                'http' => array(
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'header'  =>  array('Content-Type: application/json'),
                    'content' => $postdata
                )
            );
            $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
            $result = file_get_contents('http://149.56.127.82/daem.search', false, $context);
            $de = json_decode($result);
            return $de->token;
        }
```